# tfs merge based on simple file difference

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging

Could I merge branches in the TFS based on simple file difference?

For example, 

1) I create a DEV branch from the MAIN branch

2) Modify some code in the MAIN branch

And I want to merge MAIN branch with the DEV code.

Basically, TFS wouldn`t allow me this kind of merge cause it would suppose that there were no pending changes in th DEV though the files will be  definitely different.
Can I do it with some console commands or some wise UI manipulations? Could I control this kind of merge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If TFS isn't picking up the changes when you try to merge from Main to Dev, and you're sure that a merge hasn't already happened, you could try the following in a visual studio command prompt.

`tf merge $/MyTeamProject/Main $/MyTeamProject/Dev /recursive /force`

It's worth checking that the merge hasn't already been done though, view the history of the Dev branch to see if main has already been merged in. Just because the files are different doesn't mean that the merge hasn't already taken place.